# BEC for holography?

Tags: bose-einstein-condensate, holographic-principle

I am spending some time reading about Bose-Einstein condensation. I want to know if it is possible to use atom lasers to realize the kind of holography traditionally associated with nano-fabrication.

Many papers say that the motivation for BEC is the aforementioned holography, but I can't find if they were able to actually realize it. I am very much a novice at searching through academic literature.

The closest I have found is the work of some Japanese scientists in the 90s who were able to make 2D hologram, without a laser style beam.

---

Does anybody know if it was done, or possible can comment on some of the challenges.

Comment: It might help to get a response if you edited in some links for "many papers", and for the work of the "Japanese scientists". Off hand I cannot see how one could use a BEC to construct a hologram. The coherence in the lazing function is creating the coherent beam, a two step process. What can be the second step for the BEC so as to use it for holography?

Answer (score 2):

It's been done to some extent by [Fujio Shimizu and Jun-ichi Fujita](http://prl.aps.org/abstract/PRL/v88/i12/e123201).

Also, MIT has a [well-known lab](http://www.rle.mit.edu/cua_pub/ketterle_group/Projects_1997/atomlaser_97/atomlaser_comm.html) dedicated to this type of research headed by Dr. Ketterle .